# How to keep the code running even after exception

Tags: java, exception, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to connect to a website to get the HTML data.
I have a list of around 1000 URLs that I need to pull the data from and I am iterating on these URLs. For few scenarios, I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
```

This stops the processing of the remaining URLs. I have tried to change the timeout() to timeout(0), but this lets the code to run for that URL endlessly.

Is there a way that I can skip the URLs where I get an exception so that the code runs for the remaining ones.

Comment: Can’t you catch the exception? I’ve never used Jsoup, mind.

Comment: Catching the exception makes the code stop for other URLs in the list

Comment: I mistakenly put for loop inside my try block. Silly mistake.

Comment: you learnt something so. Perhaps consider upvoting and/or accepting any answer which helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `try`-`catch` inside your loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        try {
            //your code goes here
        } catch (ExceptionType name) {
            //error-handling code
        }
    }
}
```

Learn more about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html).

Comment: Oh! I mistakenly put for loop inside the try block. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your call within a `try { ... } catch (E e) { ... }` clause

```
try {
    // Connect to the website
} catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
    ste.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need the code in a try-catch block and after catching this exception you can handle by writing this into a logger or so. Handling the exception will make the program continue.